# Why program doesn't see my library in main called "geneticLibrary/geneticProgram.hpp"?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am stuck for hours now so I will ask here even for cost of bad reputation.

Why my main program can't see `"geneticLibrary/geneticProgram.hpp"`? I'm following next github example *https://github.com/ttroy50/cmake-examples/tree/master/02-sub-projects/A-basic*.

I have this code in main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <fstream>

#include "geneticLibrary/geneticProgram.hpp"
    
using json = nlohmann::json;   

int main(){
        std::ifstream i("../data/data.json");
        if(!i){
                std::cout << "File doesn't exist" << std::endl;
                return 1;
        }
        json j;
        i >> j;
        std::cout << j.dump() << std::endl;
        
}
```

I got this message:

```
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/geneticLibrary/CMakeFiles/geneticLibrary.dir/geneticProgram.cpp.o
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/src/geneticLibrary/geneticProgram.cpp:5:10: fatal error: geneticLibrary/geneticProgram.hpp: No such file or directory
    5 | #include "geneticLibrary/geneticProgram.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/geneticLibrary/CMakeFiles/geneticLibrary.dir/build.make:63: src/geneticLibrary/CMakeFiles/geneticLibrary.dir/geneticProgram.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:172: src/geneticLibrary/CMakeFiles/geneticLibrary.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I have following tree structure:

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── data
│   └── data.json
├── include
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── json
│       ├── appveyor.yml
│       ├── benchmarks
.
.
.
│       │       └── main.cpp
│       └── wsjcpp.yml
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── geneticLibrary
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── geneticProgram.cpp
        └── include
            └── geneticProgram.hpp
```

And last here is the output of `cmake --trace-source=CMakeLists.txt ..`.

```
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/CMakeLists.txt(1):  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4 )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/CMakeLists.txt(2):  project(GeneticProgram )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/CMakeLists.txt(4):  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/CMakeLists.txt(6):  add_subdirectory(include )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/CMakeLists.txt(4):  set(JSON_BuildTests OFF CACHE INTERNAL  )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/CMakeLists.txt(15):  add_subdirectory(json )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(1):  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(7):  project(nlohmann_json VERSION 3.9.1 LANGUAGES CXX )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(13):  set(MAIN_PROJECT OFF )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(14):  if(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(22):  include(ExternalProject )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(28):  if(POLICY CMP0077 )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(30):  cmake_policy(SET CMP0077 NEW )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(33):  option(JSON_BuildTests Build the unit tests when BUILD_TESTING is enabled. ${MAIN_PROJECT} )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(34):  option(JSON_Install Install CMake targets during install step. ${MAIN_PROJECT} )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(35):  option(JSON_MultipleHeaders Use non-amalgamated version of the library. OFF )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(36):  option(JSON_ImplicitConversions Enable implicit conversions. ON )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(37):  option(JSON_Diagnostics Enable better diagnostic messages. OFF )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(38):  option(JSON_CI Enable CI build targets. OFF )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(40):  if(JSON_CI )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(47):  include(GNUInstallDirs )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(49):  set(NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME} )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(50):  set(NLOHMANN_JSON_CONFIG_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME} CACHE INTERNAL  )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(51):  set(NLOHMANN_JSON_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR} )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(52):  set(NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGETS_EXPORT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(53):  set(NLOHMANN_JSON_CMAKE_CONFIG_TEMPLATE cmake/config.cmake.in )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(54):  set(NLOHMANN_JSON_CMAKE_CONFIG_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(55):  set(NLOHMANN_JSON_CMAKE_VERSION_CONFIG_FILE ${NLOHMANN_JSON_CMAKE_CONFIG_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(56):  set(NLOHMANN_JSON_CMAKE_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE ${NLOHMANN_JSON_CMAKE_CONFIG_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(57):  set(NLOHMANN_JSON_CMAKE_PROJECT_TARGETS_FILE ${NLOHMANN_JSON_CMAKE_CONFIG_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(58):  set(NLOHMANN_JSON_PKGCONFIG_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/pkgconfig )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(60):  if(JSON_MultipleHeaders )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(63):  else()
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(64):  set(NLOHMANN_JSON_INCLUDE_BUILD_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/single_include/ )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(65):  message(STATUS Using the single-header code from ${NLOHMANN_JSON_INCLUDE_BUILD_DIR} )
-- Using the single-header code from /home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/single_include/
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(68):  if(NOT JSON_ImplicitConversions )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(72):  if(JSON_Diagnostics )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(80):  add_library(${NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME} INTERFACE )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(81):  add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}::${NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME} ALIAS ${NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME} )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(82):  if(${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.8.0 )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(84):  else()
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(85):  target_compile_features(${NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME} INTERFACE cxx_std_11 )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(88):  target_compile_definitions(${NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME} INTERFACE JSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=$<BOOL:${JSON_ImplicitConversions}> JSON_DIAGNOSTICS=$<BOOL:${JSON_Diagnostics}> )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(95):  target_include_directories(${NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME} INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${NLOHMANN_JSON_INCLUDE_BUILD_DIR}> $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include> )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(103):  if(MSVC )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(115):  CONFIGURE_FILE(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/pkg-config.pc.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.pc )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(124):  if(JSON_BuildTests )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(134):  include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(138):  configure_file(cmake/nlohmann_jsonConfigVersion.cmake.in ${NLOHMANN_JSON_CMAKE_VERSION_CONFIG_FILE} @ONLY )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(143):  configure_file(${NLOHMANN_JSON_CMAKE_CONFIG_TEMPLATE} ${NLOHMANN_JSON_CMAKE_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE} @ONLY )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/include/json/CMakeLists.txt(149):  if(JSON_Install )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/CMakeLists.txt(8):  add_subdirectory(src )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/src/CMakeLists.txt(1):  add_subdirectory(geneticLibrary )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/src/geneticLibrary/CMakeLists.txt(1):  project(geneticLibrary )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/src/geneticLibrary/CMakeLists.txt(3):  add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} geneticProgram.cpp )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/src/geneticLibrary/CMakeLists.txt(6):  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/src/geneticLibrary/CMakeLists.txt(8):  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/CMakeLists.txt(10):  add_subdirectory(apps )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/apps/CMakeLists.txt(2):  add_executable(genetic_program main.cpp )
/home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/apps/CMakeLists.txt(5):  target_link_libraries(genetic_program PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json PUBLIC geneticLibrary )
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/vasek/project/GeneticProgram/build
```

Thanks in advace.

**EDIT: reprex**

In apps file:

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(genetic_program main.cpp)


target_link_libraries(genetic_program 
        PUBLIC geneticLibrary)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "geneticLibrary/geneticProgram.hpp"
        
int main(){
return 1;
}
```

In src/ file:
CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(geneticLibrary)
```

In geneticLibrary/ file:

CMakeLists.txt

```
project(geneticLibrary)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
        geneticProgram.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        )
```

geneticProgram.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "geneticLibrary/geneticProgram.hpp"
```

In include file geneticProgram.hpp

```
class GeneticProgram {
        public:
};
```

Comment: what's in your cmake files? please provide a [mre]

Comment: tried using brackets <>?

Comment: @FCR Thanks for answer but replacing quotes with angle bracket didn't help.

Comment: For being able to `#include<geneticLibrary/geneticProgram.hpp>` you need to have some directory, which contains `geneticLibrary` **subdirectory** and which in turn contains `geneticProgram.hpp`. I see no such directory in your hierarchy. Note, that referenced project has hierarchy `sublibrary1/include/sublib1/sublib1.h`, so with directory `sublibrary1/include` being include one, it is possible to `#include <sublib1/sublib1.h>`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for the answer. You totally hit it. I overlooked the ```sublib1/``` in referenced project. God now I feel stupid. Thanks again.